# Пустой ViewBag во View

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Здравствуйте, я пытаюсь передать из контроллера во View, но ViewBag в представлении всегда пустой, что я не так делаю?
Представление

```
   @if (item.Value is TV)
    {

        using (@Html.BeginForm("TV/" + item.Key, "Applience"))
        {
            <button type="submit" name="action" value="OnOff"><img src="~/Images/retro-tv-icon-61526.png" /></button>
            <br />
            <button type="submit" name="action" value="show">Show</button>
            if ((List<string>)ViewBag.List != null)
            {
                Html.RenderPartial("TV", (List<string>)ViewBag.list);
            }
            <input type="text" name="channelTV" />
            <button type="submit" name="action" value="AddChannel">Add Channel</button>
            <br />
            <button type="submit" name="action" value="Down">-</button>
            <button type="submit" name="action" value="Up">+</button>
            <br />
            <button type="submit" name="action" value="Prev"><-</button>
            <button type="submit" name="action" value="Next">-></button>
        }
    }
```

Контроллер

```
         public ActionResult TV(int id, string action, string channelTV)
    {
        IDictionary<int, Applience> applienceDictionary = (SortedDictionary<int, Applience>)Session["Apps"];
        TV tv = applienceDictionary[id] as TV;
        switch (action)
        {
            case "OnOff":
                tv.On_Off();
                break;
            case "AddChannel":
                tv.AddChannel(channelTV);
                break;
            case "Prev":
                tv.PrevChannel();
                break;
            case "Next":
                tv.NextChannel();
                break;
            case "Down":
                tv.Down();
                break;
            case "Up":
                tv.Up();
                break;
            case "show":
                List<string> list = tv.ShowChannels();
                ViewBag.List = list;
                    break;

        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы неправильно

1. вызываете `return RedirectToAction("Index");` в конце `TV`. `RedirectToAction` означает команду браузеру запросить страницу по другому url, что вызовет метод Index Вашего контроллера в контексте нового запроса - новый контроллер с своим (пустым) `ViewBag`'ом. Используйте `return View("Index");`
2. присваиваете `ViewBag.List = list;` только в `case "show":`.